# Давай встретимся в ТЦ «Гранд каньон» / «Гранд Каньон»

Tags: орфография

Как корректно?

> Давай встретимся в ТЦ «Гранд каньон» / «Гранд Каньон».

Answer (score 1):

Корректно, как грандканьоновцы сами себя обозвали и попали в документы и на карты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: Адрес просп. Энгельса, 154, Санкт-Петербург]

***Давай встретимся в ТЦ «Гранд Каньон»!***